Show text on ribbon in excel office js
I am developing excel-addin using angular and Office JS API.I want to display a text message in angular toast and normal text on the right side of the ribbon/menu bar of excel.
I want functionality like in the below image.

How to implement the above functionality? Or is it possible or not with the excel-addins?

You can have a custom Push menu and a menu item that opens a non-modal dialog that has any HTML content you want. But you cannot control the location of the dialog. It will open in the center of the Excel window. Users will have to drag it out of the way.
You implement the custom menu as a function command.
The code in the function that is run by the menu item calls the displayDialogAsync. For many examples of how to use it, see Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins.

what about that Last refresh text on right side any way to implement that with office js excel api ?
